# python url regexp

Tags: python, regex, urllib2

I have a regexp and i want to add output of regexp to my url

for exmaple

```
url = 'blabla.com'
r = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?</a>))

r output - /any_string/on/any/server/
```

but a dont know how to make get-request with regexp output

```
blabla.com/any_string/on/any/server/
```

Comment: You can start by rereading what you asked, and formulate better.

Comment: <p>(.*?</a>) seems weird. Did you mean <a>(.*?</a>) ?? In all cases, I don't really get your question. Could you reformulate ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to parse html. Use a real parser.

I suggest using the [`lxml.html`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html) parser. [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) [supports](http://codespeak.net/lxml/dev/xpathxslt.html#xpath) [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), which is a very powerful way of querying structured documents. There's a ready-to-use `make_links_absolute()` method that does what you ask. It's also very fast.

As an example, in this question's page HTML source code (the one you're reading now) there's this part:

```
<li><a id="nav-tags" href="/tags">Tags</a></li>
```

The xpath expression `//a[@id='nav-tags']/@href` means: *"Get me the `href` attribute of all `<a>` tags with `id` attribute equal to `nav-tags`"*. Let's use it:

```
from lxml import html

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423822/python-url-regexp'

doc = html.parse(url).getroot()
doc.make_links_absolute()
links = doc.xpath("//a[@id='nav-tags']/@href")
print links
```

The result:

```
['http://stackoverflow.com/tags']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get beautiful soup:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing+a+Document

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup.findAll('p')
```